# Using kgdb to debug the Linux kernel on two laptops without a serial port, is this possible?

Tags: kernel

I want to use one laptop as a development machine and another laptop as a target machine.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/kgdb.html

"Two machines are required for using kgdb. One of these machines is a development machine and the other is the target machine. "